# create dynamic assoc array from string php

Tags: php, associative-array

I have a string like "create:this:assoc:array"

I want to create from this string

```
$array["create"]["this"]["assoc"]["array"] = "data"
```

what i have is

```
static public function add($data_path, $data) 
{
    if(!empty($data) && !empty($data_path)) {
        $keys = explode(":", $data_path);
        $looper = array();
        $length = count($keys) - 1;
        for ($i=0; $i <= $length ; $i++) 
        {
            if($i == $length)
                @$looper[$keys[$i]] = $data;
            else
            {

                @$looper[$keys[$i]] = $keys[$i+1];
            }
        }// end for loop
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($looper);
                echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this

```
 $s = "create:this:assoc:array";
 $array = array_reverse(explode(":", $s));
 $result = "data";
 foreach($array as $key => $value){
      $result = array($value => $result);
 }
 print_r($result);
```

Comment: looks better than my! :) but you need to place `$data` at the end of the tree

Comment: not yet, now it's [0] => "data", should be $result = "data"; will be Array ( [create] => Array ( [this] => Array ( [assoc] => Array ( [array] => data ) ) ) )

Comment: and $result = array("data"); has to be $result = $data; because it will add an array to the end.

Comment: this is a full working one thnx to qwertmax

    static public function add($data_path, $data) 
    {
        if(!empty($data) && !empty($data_path)) {
            $array = array_reverse(explode(":", $data_path));
            $result = $data;
             foreach($array as $key => $value){
                  $result = array($value => $result);
             }
        }
    }